# How do I make my Google Account picture fit exactly in that box?

Tags: google-account

I uploaded my picture in the Google account but it doesn't fit in there. Can anyone please help me and tell me how I can resize he picture so that it fits in the Google account picture?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to want to resize it to 250px by 250px. You can use [this](http://www.picresize.com/) tool to make an image a custom size without tinkering with an image manipulation program.